# Change base URL of multi-site install

Tags: uri, multi-sites

I've searched a bit for the answer to this, but all the answers seem to refer to single sites, or they just don't work (or I'm doing them wrong).

I have an out-of-the-box Bitnami image setup on Amazon EC2, and when I point my domain to the server, then visit the domain, I need to put a `/drupal` on the end to get to the drupal sites.

I need to figure out how to make `example.com` and `example2.com` point to the drupal installation instead of `example.com/drupal` and `example2.com/drupal`.

Is this a drupal configuration that I need to change, or an Apache configuration, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more than likely an apache configuration.  Changing it to the RewriteBase /drupal like above will simply allow drupal to know that /drupal is where the site is installed.  You need to either look into moving the files into the original directory that the domain is pointed to, or look into finding the apache virtual host file and point it to the /drupal folder.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your site's `.htaccess` file you should see this:

```
# Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
# VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
# For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
# modify the following line:
# RewriteBase /drupal
```

You should be able to fix the problem you're having by uncommenting the last line, so it now looks like this:

```
# Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
# VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
# For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
# modify the following line:
RewriteBase /drupal
```

Hope that helps... Let me know if you're still having an issue though. :)